# DSE solr query not working from CQL

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am new to DSE/Solr and I am trying to index regular/json fields in Cassandra table using Field Transformer. Both input/output transformer workers fine and I am able to search/filter using Solr admin UI. But when I try to execute the same from CQL it failing with following error. I am using DSE 5.0.3

> ServerError: Error while creating field
>   '_uniqueKey{type=cql3CompositeKey_str,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,docValues,
>   required=true}' from value 'null'
>
> Query: select party_id from custshard_ne_interface where
>   solr_query='{"q":"*:*","fq":"businesskey:10.10.2.15,NA,NA,NA,3"}';

Schema.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieLongField" name="TrieLongField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.UUIDField" name="UUIDField"/>
</types>
<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="party_id" stored="true" required="true" type="StrField" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" docValues="true"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="sh_coll_uuid" stored="true" required="true" type="UUIDField" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" docValues="true"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="ne_id" stored="true" required="true" type="StrField" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" docValues="true"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="businesskey" stored="true" required="true" type="StrField" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" docValues="true"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="clctor_id" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="ifc_json" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="neIpAddress" stored="false" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="neHostName" stored="false" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="ifcName" stored="false" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="ifcType" stored="false" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="ipAddress" stored="false" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="macAddress" stored="false" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="ipMask" stored="false" type="StrField"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>(party_id,sh_coll_uuid,ne_id,businesskey)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it worked by adding auto generated field _uniqueKey as part of FieldOutputTransformer which has got the composite key values as string array

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a little late - but I would actually recommend not using a transformer and doing this natively with UDT's.  See the attached blog post - it's much easier.  https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/json-and-dse-search